# What Java library to use for iOS APN notifications?

Tags: library, java, ios, programming, notification

I need to create backend in Spring Boot for push notifications for iOS,
but I only came across 3 libraries: java-apns, javapns and pushy. The first two haven't been worked on for several years, and pushy is still in 0.x.x versions. Is it better to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for this? They have a complete solution and it's easy to implement with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Pushy](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy) in many projects (including one with Spring Boot); don't let the 0.x version number fool you. It's [maintained on a regular basis](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/commits/master) and (very handy) supports [token-based connection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns) with authorization keys (.p8 files) which (if you choose so) **never expire** (the old .p12 certificates need to be renewed each year).

If you use Maven, it's as simple as

1. adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
    <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.8</version>
</dependency>
```

2. creating the APNS client

```
APNS_CLIENT = new ApnsClientBuilder().setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST).setSigningKey(
    ApnsSigningKey.loadFromInputStream(new FileInputStream("APN.p8"), teamID, keyID))
    .build()
```

3. creating the payload

```
ApnsPayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = new ApnsPayloadBuilder();
payloadBuilder.setAlertBody("While processing " + site + " an exception was thrown: " + e.getMessage());
payloadBuilder.setAlertTitle("❌️ Exception thrown");
payloadBuilder.setSound("default");
String payload = payloadBuilder.buildWithDefaultMaximumLength();
```

4. and sending the notification:

```
SimpleApnsPushNotification pushNotification = new SimpleApnsPushNotification(deviceToken, applicationIdentifier, payload);
PushNotificationFuture<SimpleApnsPushNotification, PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>> sendNotificationFuture = APNS_CLIENT.sendNotification(pushNotification);
PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushNotificationResponse = sendNotificationFuture.get();
if (!pushNotificationResponse.isAccepted()) {
    System.err.println("Notification rejected by the APNs gateway: " + pushNotificationResponse.getRejectionReason());
}
```